# Is it possible to scroll a scroll view in adapter when getView

Tags: android

I tried something like this but no luck. Is there any alternative?

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view != null) { 
           holder = view.getTag();     
    } else {             
        view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.something , parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder); 

    }

    holder.scrollView.scrollTo(x,y);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## edit

according to the comment :

> Once i move the list view, i expect the scroll scroll to the x that is
> set. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

You need to listen to the scroll event of the scrollview something like this should work:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        ScrollView sv = absListView.findViewById(R.id.yourScrollView);
        sv.scrollTo(x,y);
        /** 
         ** absListView is the view that you scrolled to in your list view
         ** then you get your scrollView from the findViewById()
         ** then you scroll that scroll view using the method scrollTo(x,y)
         **/ 
    }
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a list view(vertical) and each row has on scrollview.
When i scroll to right hand side most i set the xy to adapter.
Once i move the list view, i expect the scroll scroll to the x that is set.
Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Often it's helpful to give a bit of explanation with an answer. You can always [edit] your answer.

Comment: @user3068613 then its a different question you are asking on how to apply scroll to a scroll view originally. i will update the answer to adapt it to this comment, please update your question for others to understand.

Comment: @O.Jones yes i know i always try to add as much explanation as i can, but as for this example, there is not much to talk about.

Comment: @user3068613 check the update please you dont need the getView you need to know when you are scrolling the list to make a scroll on the scrollView inside that list

Comment: Your answer works great. Thanks.
Just a thing about performance issue.
Your answer need to scroll all scrollView,
What i wanna do is scroll the visible scrollview. If the hidden scrollView becomes visible, i scroll those will-appear scrollView.
I accept this answer because i have maximum 10 rows